# How to build a customizable Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, customization

As a learning project, I am developing a forum application with Rails 3.1 for the Kung Fu club I'm in. I would like to manage my code on Github, so others in the club or anyone else could use it. The idea is to put a 'plain', customizable version on Github, but manage customizations, e.g., different styles or a different log-on scheme, in another, more private git repository.

What is the best way for making a Rails application customizable? These customizations might include: CSS code, Javascript code, HTML views, seed data (e.g., user groups in my club), complete additional views or overwriting single view methods. Ideally, customizations live in a separate directory so they, too, can be put in a git repository separately.

Here are some approaches that came to my mind:

- two repositories, one being a clone of the other with customizations (disadvantages: many git operations for a simple update on prod server, error-prone because the same code exists twice)
- separate solutions for CSS, JS etc.: put all modifications in a directory `custom` (which is managed using a second, private repo and could be mounted as a git submodule) whose contents are included via `*= require_tree my_sports_club/stylesheets` etc., but what about routes, views and controllers?
- the Rails way to go which I don't know yet - maybe something like: develop my app as a gem, then install this gem into an existing app which then overrides certain parts of my gem? I took a look at how [spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) does that, but that looks quite complicated to me and also seems to be unhandy for ongoing development.

I'd be interested how other people approach this problem and what the limitations are.

**Edit:** Maybe I should describe this as a mixed Rails/Git problem--I am trying to keep an off-the-shelf application in a git repository (i.e. a forum with plain gray background without a logo), and I want to keep all the data and code needed for a customized version, an "instance" of the the off-the-shelf version, tailored to the needs of the deployment domain in another repository (the sports club forum with pre-defined user groups, a logo etc.). And I want to be able to easily switch between those two, so I don't get to see the instance website only after deploying it on the production site.

Comment: Rails already *is* customizable. If you want a CMS that you can change around via a web-based GUI, use WordPress. That isn't what Rails is.

Comment: @meagar: I am not talking about an UI for customization. Have you read my question?

Comment: customizable from whose perspective? Do you want a fixed set of gems, or is that open to customization also?

Comment: @prusswan, meagar: Sorry, obviously I haven't made my question clear enough, please see my edit above (didn't mean to be rude). Hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The Rails way (at least my understanding of it) would be to build the functionality as a Rails Engine.

For good examples on how to do this, I would look at projects like [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) and [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). They are definitely complicated projects, but they provide a lot of the features you seem to be looking for.

RailsAdmin, for example, is installed as a gem and provides a complete admin interface with almost no configuration necessary. When you want to change its behavior, there is an initializer file that allows you to pass in how to authenticate users, render forms, group models, etc.

This approach could easily be applied to a forum, which initially would really only have to be told about your user model. Everything else could be assumed and optionally overwritten in the config.

Devise shows a method for taking configuration a step further. There is a Devise generator that copies the gem's built in views to the application's `views/` folder, where they can be freely modified and override the gem views.

Since you mention this is a learning project, however, I don't recommend you just jump in with all that at once. Just build a normal Rails app and get it working the way you want it to with all the features you want. Once you've got that done (and it'll take longer than you think), your next project can be to extract the forum functionality into a customizable engine.

Comment: +1 for the Rails Engine advice and pointers to other projects. This actually answers a couple of questions I was going to ask in a month or so :). I'm still hoping for an answer fitting my problem even better, that's why I don't accept this as an answer for now.

Comment: This is a strange question. You want to be able to deploy a single application with both a generic version and customized version of itself, with each version managed separately in git? And switch between the two versions while the application is running?

Comment: No. Possibly the word 'customization' was badly chosen because of the associations people have about it. I don't want to switch. I want one version for the public (on github), and one 'instance' for a specific cause (not on github because it contains logos etc). I just learned git better, and the way I'll do it now is simply as a branch with customizations that I'm never merging back into the master branch.